# Current status US 4132029

Tags: licensing, us4132029

Looking for the current status of this patent.
Is it still valid?
Who holds the rights to it, or who owns it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to check on the status of a US Patent:

1. The first place to look is Google Patents: [US4132029](https://www.google.com/patents/US4132029?dq=4132029)
2. The second place to look is the [Public Pair](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3797/1767) system at USPTO.

The subject patent [US4132029](https://www.google.com/patents/US4132029?dq=4132029) was issued Jan 2, 1979:

[image]

From Public Pair you can also see that the patent was issued on Jan 2, 1979.

[image]

For older applications (filed prior to Jun 8, 1995), the term of the patent was generally **[17 years from the date of issuance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent_in_the_United_States)** (or 20 years from the earliest priority date, whichever is later).

So the subject **patent is expired**.  No patent rights to own and the invention is now in the public domain.

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes be complicated to calculate when a particular patent will expire. Not in this case. It was issued in 1979 and at that time patents expired 17 years after being granted. It has been expired for over 15 years.