# collection of medical data online

Tags: pair, status, claim-construction, expiry, us20060184393

In reference to the patent: [US20060184393](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060184393)

Does this patent implies that no one trying to collect medical data online can actually do it? Is not this patent too broad and lacking of a discovery? Can you patent a common sense approach to collect data like the one proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is broader but was never granted a patent, applicant failed to reply examiner objections.

> status on date 10-23-2009-- Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an
>   Office Action

presently no child applications are pending for this application and it seems all doors are closed for this application.

you are also requested to refer Ask patents another answer on [how to check USPTO patent status on official register.](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/4722/11895)