# Wondering about some technical aspects and legal process prior to build a patented structure

Tags: wo2008021980a3, us7448400

I need to get in touch with the person that holds a patent in order to build it.

How do I do this?

Comment: That number is for an international PCT application. Its counterpart U.S. application has issued as US 7448400. The inventors name and address on the the face of the U.S. patent.

Comment: I see the name of the inventor, the thing is I cannot find a phone number or an email adress.

Comment: Where can I find the contact info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I contact the inventor of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-inventor-of-a-patent)

Answer (score 1):

You can typically contact the inventor through his or her attorney. The attorney's contact information is available on [Public PAIR](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3797/1767).

For the subject patent US7448400 the contact information for the attorney is as follows: [Dianoosh Salehi at Snell & Wilmer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0pN.png) LLP in Costa Mesa, CA, telephone 714-427-7404

[image]