# Update in public pair

Tags: public, pair, update

Can anyone tell me how long it takes the uspto to update public pair? I am trying to determine if a competitor submitted a response to an office action. Pair does not show it to be filed (should have been filed two days ago)in the IFW. The application is published.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the US Appl. No?

Comment: Note that the PAIR search is notoriously picky about the format of patent numbers, as described in the comments for [a related question](http://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3798/14417).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the file on PAIR, any updates should essentially be in real time.  In other words, once an office action response (or other document) is filed in a publicly available case, that filling immediately becomes public.